# Can't play minecraft offline without logging in on blocked network

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking

I am signed in on minecraft, but whenever I open the launcher it logs me out and I can't log back in again because the sign-in portal is blocked by my network. I can play the game when I turn my internet off (it doesn't sign me out that way), but once signed out I cannot login and play offline. Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: "it doesn't sign me out that way" But isn't that exactly what you are describing with "whenever I open the launcher it logs me out"?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a firewall. Can't tell you how to fix it without knowing what PC you're using. Just search "how to reset firewalls (Computer)".

Comment: It sounds like a school network and they're probably using the computer for purposes the network administrators do not approve of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your best bet would be to use a VPN.  It would allow you to be accessing a different network virtually and it should let you get around this issue.  Or as you mentioned you can just play it solo offline.  Networks often times at schools and/or workplace environments will have these network restrictions that basically blows network traffic or access to certain types of content, in this case it would be games.